# Order a column by average sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table `Reviews` with columns `MovieID` and `Rating`.

In this table, Ratings are associated to a particular MovieID.

For example, MovieID 123 can have 500 ratings, ranging from 1-5.

I want to display N-Top movies, with the highest average rating(rounded to 4 decimals) on the top, in the format:

```
movieID|avg
123    : 4.06
512    : 4.01
744    : 3.68
23     : 2.51
```

Is this query the right way to do it?

```
SELECT MovieID, ROUND(AVG(CAST(Rating AS FLOAT)), 4) as avg 
from Reviews order by avg desc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the correct way to do it. When you use aggregate function like `avg()` you need to include a `group by` clause that determines over what item the function should be applied.

In your case you should do

```
SELECT TOP 5
  MovieID, ROUND(AVG(CAST(Rating AS FLOAT)), 4) as avg 
FROM Reviews 
GROUP BY MovieID
ORDER BY ROUND(AVG(CAST(Rating AS FLOAT)), 4) DESC
```

to get the top 5 ratings. The `TOP 5` limits the records returned to the top 5 as determined by the `order by` clause.

Note that if the top 6 movies happen to have the same average rating you'd still only get five (and it would be undetermined which five of the six). If you want ties to count as one then you should look at the `rank()` function instead.

Answer (score 1):

Here is query which will solve your problem:

```
SELECT MovieID, ROUND(AVG(rating),4) AS avg
FROM your_table
GROUP BY MovieID
ORDER BY ROUND(AVG(rating),4) DESC LIMIT 4
```

Here I have taken `N = 4` as in your sample output from above.  Also, you will need to replace `your_table` in this query with the actual name of your table.  Your original query was going in the wrong direction because it wasn't making use of the `GROUP BY` function to find the average rating for each movie.

Answer (score 1):

The following might work better:

```
Table 
"input" with data:
movieId:rating
A      : 4
A      : 5
B      : 2
```

Then the query would be:

```
SELECT ROUND(AVG(rating),4) as avg_rating, movieId 
FROM input 
GROUP BY movieId  
ORDER BY AVG(rating) DESC;
```